# Center landscape table in two-column environment

Tags: tables, two-column, center, aastex

I have two tables that have their own designated pages in landscape mode. The rest of the document is in portrait mode, in 2-column AASTeX. I am using `\{sidewaystable*}` to achieve this; i.e:

```
\documentclass[preprint2]{aastex631}

\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\graphicspath{{./}{figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|llllllll|}
\hline
SOURCE &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F275W} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F275W\_err} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F336W} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F336W\_err} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F438W} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F438W\_err} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{F547M\_err} &
  F547M \\ \hline
M95src1     & 4.54351e-15 & 6.08423e-17 & 3.19125e-15 & 4.70934e-17 & 1.81730e-15 & 3.94618e-17 & 9.09317e-16 & 3.22922e-17 \\
M74src1     & 6.31362e-16 & 8.13120e-18 & 4.60251e-16 & 6.24878e-18 & 2.88855e-16 & 3.62256e-18 & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
M72src2     & 2.84990e-16 & 3.33756e-18 & 1.85942e-16 & 2.52191e-18 & 8.75504e-17 & 1.52848e-18 & 4.30000e-17 & 1.26348e-18 \\
NGC1313src1 & 2.63232e-15 & 3.20422e-17 & 1.71869e-15 & 2.18489e-17 & 8.98710e-16 & 1.18666e-17 & 6.34298e-16 & 8.85486e-18 \\
NGC1313src2 & 5.71102e-16 & 7.54246e-18 & 4.19703e-16 & 5.78055e-18 & 3.66732e-16 & 5.17091e-18 & 2.42669e-16 & 3.81882e-18 \\
NGC1512src2 & 6.49137e-16 & 9.23595e-18 & 3.85527e-16 & 6.66176e-18 & 2.27656e-16 & 6.59644e-18 & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
NGC1566src2 & 1.06902e-15 & 1.44085e-17 & 6.14148e-16 & 9.05500e-18 & 3.76748e-16 & 6.67373e-18 & 1.74966e-16 & 5.18092e-18 \\
NGC1566src1 & 6.33580e-16 & 9.37622e-18 & 4.21404e-16 & 6.57187e-18 & 2.94168e-16 & 5.93872e-18 & 1.80367e-16 & 3.85296e-18 \\
NGC4485src1 & 1.43810e-15 & 1.81151e-17 & 7.93797e-16 & 1.03454e-17 & 4.15976e-16 & 5.58101e-18 & 1.98965e-16 & 3.07794e-18 \\
NGC4485src2 & 1.18433e-15 & 1.44646e-17 & 7.86436e-16 & 1.02521e-17 & 4.61686e-16 & 6.01165e-18 & 2.26742e-16 & 3.25913e-18 \\
NGC4656src1 & 9.91670e-16 & 1.35562e-17 & 6.78700e-16 & 9.86215e-18 & 6.46170e-16 & 1.01963e-17 & 4.59020e-16 & 7.40012e-18 \\
NGC4656src2 & 3.50861e-15 & 4.46549e-17 & 2.96403e-15 & 3.79962e-17 & 1.62303e-15 & 2.20544e-17 & 8.73478e-16 & 1.20053e-17 \\
M51src1     & 2.54969e-15 & 3.14520e-17 & 1.32539e-15 & 1.81867e-17 & 8.17771e-16 & 1.33309e-17 & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
M51src2     & 6.96234e-16 & 9.25907e-18 & 4.67648e-16 & 6.47452e-18 & 3.44582e-16 & 5.21984e-18 & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
NGC7793src1 & 2.07692e-15 & 3.08765e-17 & 1.14235e-15 & 2.09407e-17 & 5.76197e-16 & 1.10729e-17 & 2.72390e-16 & 5.20281e-18 \\
NGC7793src2 & 1.14260e-15 & 1.33521e-17 & 7.44061e-16 & 9.13160e-18 & 6.56435e-16 & 8.65997e-18 & 3.76752e-16 & 5.22566e-18 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Photometry in F275W, F336W, F438W and F547M}
\label{tab:phot1}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

When I do this, the tables appear to be locked into where the text columns would be in portrait mode - see the attached image. I want them to be centered on the page. How do I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

[image: How my current layout looks...]

Comment: Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document. Testing your table fragment with `article` document class gives expected nice result.

Comment: Just updated it. Thank you.